# How to plot the average of ROC curves?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scikit-learn, roc

I am attempting to perform outlier detection and I have 15 different test sets and 3 different models (a PCA-based classifier, One Class SVM and Isolation Forest).

For PCA-based classification, I have written my own code for generating ROC curves. I have 2 lists `pcafprs` and `pcatprs`, each of which has 15 sublists, each sublist representing the False Positive Ratios and True Positive Ratios, required to plot the ROC curve.

For One-Class SVM and Isolation Forest, I can get the (fpr, tpr) from `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`. Similar to PCA, I have `ocsvmfprs` and `ocsvmtprs` for One-Class SVM, and `isoforestfprs` and `isoforesttprs` for Isolation Forest.

For each test set, I can iterate over the FPR and TPR lists and plot the ROC curve. The code might look like:
`for i in range(len(pcafprs)):
    plt.plot(pcafprs[i], pcatprs[i]) #Plot the ROC curve
    plt.show()`

For each of the 3 models, I want to be able to plot the average of all 15 ROC curves for the 15 test sets in one graph. I cannot simply do np.mean over the arrays containing the TPRs and FPRs because the FPRs returned by `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve` are all different points for each test set.

For PCA, I have tried using `np.mean(pcatprs, axis=0)` and `np.mean(pcafprs, axis=0)` to average out all the TPRs and FPRs so that I can plot a single graph which represents the mean of all the test sets. This works because for PCA I have generated the same number of FPRs and TPRs for each test set.
However, I am unable to control the no. of FPRs and TPRs returned for each test set by `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve`, and it turns out that it returns different number of values for each test set. Due to this, I cannot use `np.mean` to find the average ROC curve.

**tl,dr**: Is there a way to plot the average of multiple lines on a graph without having the equations and only having some points that lie on the lines, where we have a *different number of points available for each line*?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi @Anthony, I have updated the post to include more details, could you please check again?

Answer (score -1):

Solved by choosing a fixed set of FPRs, then using `no.interp` for each pair of (fpr,tpr) returned by `sklearn.metrics.roc_curve` to get the corresponding TPRs, then averaged all ROCs using `np.mean`